# How to identify which device is malicious

Tags: hardware

I'm facing a surprising problem : A windows 10 computer seem to use keyboard and mouse by himself on the login screen.

So I'm guessing :

- It's not a software intrusion, because it that way the program should have access to the shell and should use command by programs instead of attempt to login;
- It may be a hardware attack, there is some (know and buy) device connected by USB on this computer;

So here is my question : There is a way to identify the malicious device? And even better, to record what kind of command it's attempt to use ?(Yea, I'm playful.)

-- A bit more context
I observed this behavior after just open this laptop and leave him alone around 10 min.
The virtual keyboard was open, and the program seem quite lost by clicking on empty space where there is usually the menu icon.

Comment: Sounds more like a hardware problem.

Comment: If it's a laptop, then the malicious device (if there is one) is the laptop

Comment: Maybe there's a wireless mouse paired with the computer that someone is bumping. Or the trackpad is just oversensitive/broken.